# Spacetime dimension by variational principle

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, spacetime, variational-principle, action, spacetime-dimensions

I'm asking it out of curiosity: if hypothetically speaking spacetime had the freedom to "choose" its dimension, and it can be described by an action, is it possible to do an analytic continuation of the integral that defines it to real dimensions $n$ and apply variation principle to it? Something like
$$ \frac{\delta S}{\delta n } = 0$$
to find $n$. I suspect $\Gamma$ function will appear, but is it applicable or is it an imaginary/dumb idea?

Comment: The action specifies the dimension in a different way (_which_ different way depends on whether it's a field-theoretic or "discrete mechanics" action).

Comment: @J.G. What do you mean?

Comment: For the former, it's in the coordinates passed to the fields (not to mention the $\int d^nx$ or $\int d^{n-1}\mathbf{x}$ operator); for the latter, it's in the coordinates passed to the Lagrangian.

Comment: @J.G. I'm referring to the field-theoretic case, imagining e.g. Einstein-Hilbert action